# $cordovaInstagram returns unknown Unknown Provider

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to integrate the $cordovaInstagram plugin of ngCordova in my service:

```
.factory('ShareInstagramFactory', function($cordovaInstagram, $q) {
    var self = this;

    // Options
    var shareMessage = "Message";


    //
    // Instagram
    self.shareInstagram = function(imageData) {

        console.log("shareInstagram")

        var qInstagram = $q.defer();

        $cordovaInstagram.share(imageData, shareMessage).then(function() {
            // Worked
            qInstagram.resolve(true)
         }, function(err) {
            // Didn't work
            qInstagram.reject(err);
         });

        return qInstagram.promise;
    };

    return self;
})
```

However, I get the following issue

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$cordovaInstagramProvider%20%3C-%20$cordovaInstagram%20%3C-%20ShareInstagramFactory
```

All my other ngCordova plugins work as expected.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is an issue into that point.
I have implemented yesturday the sharewith instagram and could not make it work with ngCordova function.

However, I made it work by using directly cordova plugin call :

```
Instagram.share(canvasId, shareMsg, function(err) {
```

Therefore, remove the ngCordova provider and replace your sharing functionnaly.

Comment: Let me try... will raise it on github if it persists

Comment: window.Instagram (in my case) was available. This is why calling directly to the Instagram function works. You can confirm that window.Instagram exists by removing $cordovaInstagram dependency and adding a console.log(window.Instagram)

Comment: Moreover, I checked (rapidly) into ngCordova code yesturday and the $cordovaInstagram does exists. The issue shall be that the module $cordovaInstagram does not intanciate properly.